# error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, fortran

I obtain an error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My OS:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.2 Tina
Release:    19.2
Codename:   tina
```

I tried:

1. Running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
   ```

   gives:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   libgfortran3 is already the newest version (6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 507 not upgraded.
   ```
2. Running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
   ```

   and obtained the same error.
3. Running:

   ```
   sudo apt install apt-file && sudo apt update
   ```

   gives:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   apt-file is already the newest version (3.1.5).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 507 not upgraded.
   Reading package lists... Done
   E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
   E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
   ```
4. Running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   gives:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
   E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
   ```

What should I do, please?

**After advice:**

```
sudo apt install apt-file && sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-file is already the newest version (3.1.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 507 not upgraded.
Get:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4502 B]
Ign:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com tina InRelease                             
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Err:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com tina Release                               
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1811 B]          
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease           
Err:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
Hit:9 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                        
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease             
Ign:13 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu tina-cran40/ InRelease     
Hit:14 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease   
Err:15 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu tina-cran40/ Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 65.9.95.64 443]
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.9 kB]
Hit:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F142A4D99F16EB04
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu tina-cran40/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F142A4D99F16EB04
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: *507 not upgraded* means you've been disregarding updates for a very long time. Please address it before any further troubleshooting. You may want to try, after waiting some minutes, `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: I am not able to run this command, I obtain what is written in 3). The action ends with the error.

Comment: So check your software sources because something must be very wrong. And, of course, you may want tot try again after rebooting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe what exactly you are doing when you obtain the error (executing some program? if so, what program, and how did you install it?), as well as your Ubuntu version

Comment: I have problem with running `sudo apt install apt-file && sudo apt update` - I added the error to my question. I run the command after reboot. I install some scientific program written in fortran.

Comment: @karel I read this question, I tried `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3`, but it is installed the program gives me the same error.

Comment: Thank you, it is solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)